# Adding Rx Event Pattern to WP7 ApplicationBar Click

Tags: windows-phone-7, system.reactive

Is it possible to add an Rx event handling method to wp7 ApplicationBar item.  I tried the below mentioned code but getting a null reference exception. Please help me to avoid this issue.

```
 var res = Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(button1, "Click")
              .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
              .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(230))
              .Subscribe(

                 _ => {
                     ++i;
                     Debug.WriteLine("Clicked{0}", i);

                 }

              );
```

Comment: "but getting a null reference exception" at the time you are doing this, `Scheduler` or `Scheduler.ThreadPool` or some other bit of the puzzle is null.  You have to figure that part out (call stack, inner exceptions usually help).  Solution:  Do it later.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `FromEventPattern` rather than `FromEvent`.

Comment: There is no such method present in windows Phone.

Comment: @NithaPaul - Ah, you must be using the Rx library baked into ROM. I believe you can download the latest libraries to use instead. That will increase your XAP size, but may help.